# Trigger To Delete When Rows Are Over A Certain Amount

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm currently writing a web application that displays any sort of changes that happen within a database to the webpage. I had to write a few triggers already that insert and update a table from the table I need the information from. Because the SQL is live, I needed to create a back up table to have my webpage watch so there will be no deadlocks in the live database as it is extremely active.

I need a trigger that deletes rows from my back up table when the row amount reaches 100, is there a way to do this? I want the table to be lightweight and only display a certain amount of information at a time without taking up unnecessary space in my database

Comment: Why not make use of *system versioning* here? Make use of the built-in ability to track changes to a table and automatically rolling delete it.

Comment: I have never used system versioning before, but I will 100% look into right now! Appreciate the suggestion

Comment: An additional trigger is not a great way of handling this.  A better approach might be to have a background job that runs periodically to check and purge old records from the back-up table.

Comment: <voice-of-experience> Sounds like something I would have tried and discovered that when something went wrong I had 100 duplicate rows that had flushed out the interesting data that would have helped me diagnose the underlying problem. </voice-of-experience>